# How do i change Truffle default account after contract deployment to interact with it?

Tags: truffle, accounts

I work with Truffle and Ganache along side Windows PowerShell. Truffle's default account is `account[0]`. I deploy my contract with that. After a while, i need to interact with the contract with `account[1]`. So, i should switch Truffle's default account from `account[0]` to `account[1]`. Please guide me to do that .Please note that there is no `app.js` or `Nodejs` and i need do that in PowerShell.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can always specify the account with which you want to interact with the contract, using the `from` keyword, e.g., `instance.someFunction({from: accounts[0]})`. 
Second, you can edit the default address in the *truffle-config.js* file at `networks.advanced.from`, which equals to accounts[0] per default.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default from account through truffle console by doing:

```
yourContract.defaults({from:'new address'})
```